# problem with the import of a gpx file in any program

Tags: gps, gpx

I have difficulties to import one particular gpx file. I got it via email and it displays some tracks. 10 segments and 5500 waypoints.

i tried as follow:

- QGIS, also with GPSBabel
- Google Earth
- Movescount (I see the tracks but movecscount does not reckognise the segments)
- Garmin Basecamp
- Textedit
- gps-tracks.com; a portal for gps tracks for outdoor activist

Unfortunately, I have any information about how the file was created (which tracker, etc).

Do you have any ideas what I could try further?
In the link [GPX Vieweer](http://www.bernhard-gaul.de/gpxviewer/gpxviewerlinksvar.php?url=http://www.bernhard-gaul.de/file/liroutedl1444558164.gpx&width=1280&height=800) I was able to view the tracks but nothing more.

In [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1gkpidypec7qeg/Madeira.gpx?dl=0) link, you'll find the file.

Comment: Upload the file to some file sharing service and add a link into your question.

Comment: @user30184 good idea :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've just got some malformed data in your `<desc>` tags. After I blanked those lines (`<desc></desc>`), the GPX file loaded fine in common platforms.

Your edited file  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wgnoochqxfh5a8/Madeira.gpx?dl=0)

On a second look, I believe it's just having trouble interpreting some German characters in the description.

Comment: You are right, the file claims to be UTF-8 encoded (as GPX standard), but the umlauts are ANSI encoded. Once you change that in a text editor like notepad++, it gets loaded into QGIS.